# How to create excel file out of data on the fly from web

Tags: php, excel

How can I put a link in my web page that when clicked allows to download an .csv file containing data from my database?

Comment: Yes it is. Carry on.

Comment: @Dagon you should post that as an answer

Comment: This question isn't too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `fputcsv()`. Please follow this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fputcsv.asp) on how you can use that code.

Here is the example.

```
<?php
$list = array
(
"Peter,Griffin,Oslo,Norway",
"Glenn,Quagmire,Oslo,Norway",
);

$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");

foreach ($list as $line)
  {
  fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
  }

fclose($file); ?>
```

Comment: thnx for the help mate